# AutoHotkey - I want a script to hold the left mouse button down when I hold F9 and then do a quick click

Tags: autohotkey

I would need help with a script in AutoHotkey to keep the left mouse button pressed if I hold the F9 key and then do a short click and then the F9 key and the mouse key held down are released again with another click.

I am particularly interested in moving an object with the mouse without holding down the mouse button because of a physical handicap.

I am also open to other ideas.

Comment: Do you want the F9 key to toggle whether the mouse button is held down or not?

Comment: I want the F9 key to remain held and only hold the mouse button down with an additional mouse click. And when I do another click, I want the F9 key and mouse button to be released.

I apologize as I use the google translator to translate as my english is not good enough to explain a matter precisely.

Comment: The purpose of the F9 key is to ensure that the script is not played with every click.

Comment: So, do you want it so that the mouse needs to be clicked *while* you are holding down the F9 key in order for the script to play (and cause the mouse button to be held down)?

Comment: Yes exactly!
---
To explain the matter in detail.
I basically use a program that automatically clicks when the mouse pointer is still for 500 ms, no matter where the cursor is.
So I auto-click the F9 key (on-screen keyboard), then I auto-click an object, then I want the object to be held, and only when I auto-click again do I want both keys to be released.
At the moment I use a speech recognition program, and every time I want to hold the mouse down, I say "hold ... HOLD ..." - This is tiresome over time and annoying for people in the room. 

Answer (score 1):

Because a mouse "Click" event technically consists of a `Mouse Down` Event followed by `Mouse Up` Event, after the F9 key is pressed, the script waits for the initial click and then holds the mouse down. Then when your second click occurs, the Mouse Up event of the second Click should release the MouseButton. I tested the below on my computer (which doesn't have an on-screen keyboard with function keys), so let me know if it doesn't work properly.

```
F9::
Sleep 100
KeyWait LButton, D
KeyWait LButton
Sleep 400
Send {LButton Down}
return
```

Edit: I added a bit of delay so that it is not registered as a double-click

Comment: Thank you for the script, I am very grateful that I have received such great help.
So I have now inserted the code, but unfortunately I have no success. Unfortunately nothing happens at all. Do I have to pay attention to something when inserting?
Is it possible to change something again or use a different key?

Comment: The first thing that I would recommend you check is to make sure that the script is running. The easiest way to do this would be to insert a line at the very beginning of the script with the code `Msgbox, The Program is Running`. In order to change the key that activates the script, replace `F9::` with `NameOfKey::`. Here is the [List of Keys in AHK](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm) if you want to use a special key

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that the F9 key wouldn't be held down, since I found that kind of redundant. So the way to use the script would be" 1. Click F9. 2. MouseClick the top of the Window you want to move. 3. Move the Window to the desired position. 4. MouseClick again to release the Window.

Comment: OK. so the message comes that the script is running. Sometimes I can mark a text after 2 - 3 clicks. But that only works sporadically. But I can't move a desktop icon or a window, for example.

Comment: Ok, try to wait for ~ one second between steps 2 and 3, since in order to prevent double-clicks from occurring I had to put half a second of delay between the activation click in step two, and the action that holds the Mouse Down.